# efidisk read error

Tags: 12.04, installation, kubuntu, uefi

I am really desperate now. I had to reinstall my system on Friday. Instead of Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity I chose Kubuntu 12.04.

Installation was smooth but with booting I got efidisk read error. System worked so I thought I can ignore the whole thing. On Saturday the system didn't boot up.

I thought maybe I screwed up during installation so I reinstalled the system again. I got the same efidisk error on startup and on Sunday the system didn't start anymore again (only the grey screen showed up). I then figured out, that when I have the installation USB-Drive connected the system starts.

I googled and found an article that stated that installing from CD could solve the problem.
Guess what, I reinstalled the system again and again I get the efidisk read error.

Does anyone know what I have to do?

With the old installation (Ubuntu 12.04) I didn't have any problem.

EDIT:

Since it is not working with Kubuntu 12.04 I installed 13.10 and I can start without a problem. Evern 13.10 is buggy, right now I am happy

Answer (score 1):

What is the *exact* error message? Post a screen shot if necessary. As it is, it's not clear precisely what the error message is or what's generating it -- it could be the firmware, the boot loader, the kernel, or something else.

I do have three shot-in-the-dark suggestions for how to proceed:

- If you're dual-booting with Windows 8 or 8.1, boot to Windows and [disable the Fast Startup feature.](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) (Note that this is distinct from the fast boot option in the firmware.)
- Download the CD-R or USB flash drive version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and boot from it. If you can boot successfully from rEFInd, try installing the Debian package version, which should put it on your hard disk, with any luck removing the problem.
- Run the [Boot Repair tool.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) This can fix some types of boot problems automatically, but it's not guaranteed to work. If it doesn't work, post the URL that Boot Repair spits out; that contains potentially useful diagnostic information.

Disable Fast Startup in Windows first, if that option is applicable. Try the others only if disabling Fast Startup doesn't help or if you're not dual-booting with Windows 8/8.1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Kubuntu is a stand alone system. Haven't used Windows for about three years :-) A screen shot is not possible because the error message shows only for about 2 secs. I had to reboot the system about 7 times till I got the error message. It just says efidisk read error. I will try your suggested mehthods when I get home tonight.