# Persistent error "efidisk read error" can't use my computer, Haven't found the solution on askubuntu so new question

Tags: grub2

**I have not found any solution to my problem on askubuntu to this date** (11th Feb. 2016), which is why I created a new question, **please take this in consideration** before posting a comment. Thank you in advance.

The last time my computer was working properly, it suddenly displayed a black screen - this happens when I open too many windows-, I then force shut down. It wasn't the first or the second time I did that, but since that happened, every time I turn it on, it only displays a black screen with with white text saying:

```
error: efidisk read error
```

Under that it says:

```
grub rescue>
```

With an IT friend of mine we've tried all sorts of grub rescue commands, including:

```
set root 
set prefix
insmod normal 
normal 
boot 
reboot 
start
```

The only outputs I get (when I get any) are:

```
unknown filesystem
there is no such file 
error: efidisk read error 
unknown command
```

EDIT from comment:

I have already tried all commands related to efidisk and grub rescue found on askubuntu, which is why I created a new question.

I've tried turning it off and on again countless times, but I get the same result:

- ASUS start screen (1 second) then black screen with error message

How can fix this on my own? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related - Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/371104/efidisk-read-error

Comment: Hello. Sorry but I have already tried all commands related to efidisk and grub rescue found on askubuntu, which is why I created a new question.

Comment: Can you boot from live media (USB or Optical disk)? pleas [edit] your question with this information. thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Have you tried either chkdsk from Windows or fsck from Linux on ESP - efi system partition or the FAT32 formated partition. Often sda1, but may be different. `sudo fsck.vfat -t -a /dev/sda1`